# Circular (ring) buffer write method in C

Tags: c, file, file-io, buffer

Im trying to create an exact copy of a text file, and I am using a circular buffer.

The write method I am using is:

```
void addItem(CircularBuffer *cBuff, BufferItem *cbItem) {
    cBuff->cBuffItems[cBuff->lastInd] = *cbItem;
    cBuff->lastInd = ( ((cBuff->lastInd) + 1) % cBuff->size);
    if (cBuff->lastInd == cBuff->startInd)
    {
        cBuff->startInd = (cBuff->startInd + 1) % cBuff->size; // Overwriting full buffer.
    }
}
```

And here is how I am copying each char into the buffer:

```
BufferItem result;
char ch;
while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF ){
    result.offset = ftell(fp);
    result.data = ch;
    addItem(&cBuff, &result);
}
```

It only writes the first three characters then gives me a segmentation fault. I made sure the buffer size is big enough, ive tried different datasets, all give the same result (only the first 3 chars copied into buffer).

If I dont add it to the buffer, and just print result.offset, and result.data I get what I expect. So addItem must be the problem, If I delete the second line in addItem, it works but obviously it just overwrites the first spot.

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit:

Here is the circular buffer and circular buffer implementation:

```
// Circular buffer items.
typedef  struct {
     char  data ;
     off_t offset ;
} BufferItem ;

// Circular buffer
typedef struct {
    int startInd; // Index of first element added to buffer.
    int lastInd; // Index of most recent element added to buffer.
    int size; // Number of elements in circular buffer.
    BufferItem *cBuffItems; // Circular buffer items.
} CircularBuffer;

void initializeBuffer(CircularBuffer *cBuff, int size) {
    cBuff->cBuffItems = calloc(cBuff->size, sizeof(BufferItem));
    cBuff->size  = size + 1;
    cBuff->startInd = 0;
    cBuff->lastInd   = 0;
}
```

And like I mentioned, I did initialize the buffer, here is a simplified version of main:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        printf("Expected 3 arguments, received %d\n", argc - 1);
        return 1;
    }

    int bufSize; // Capacity of BufferItems in circular buffer.
    char *file; // Pathname of file to be copied.
    char *copy; // Name to be given to the copy.

    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &bufSize);
    file = argv[2];
    copy = argv[3];

    initializeBuffer(&cBuff, bufSize);

    // Open file to be copied.
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r" );

    // Create copy file.
    FILE *cp = fopen(copy, "w+" ); // Overwrite if file exists.

    BufferItem result;
    char ch;
    while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF ){
        result.offset = ftell(fp);
        result.data = ch;
        addItem(&cBuff, &result);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(cp);

    return 0;
}// Main.
```

Comment: What pointer values did your debugger show, when you stepped through your code (I seriously suppose you did this before asking here)?

Comment: Please show definitions for `CircularBuffer` and `BufferItem`.

Comment: Should we just take a wild guess? Or do you expect us to read your mind to see the rest of the code where the error presumably is? A couple of guesses: 1. You didn't make `cBuffItems` big enough. 2. You didn't initialize `startInd` or `lastInd` or `size`.

Comment: Also note that `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`, so `ch` should be an `int`. An `int` is necessary in order to distinguish `EOF` from valid byte values.

Comment: Please review what it takes to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) and then show us one.  Until then, you've not provided us with enough information to be able to guess what you are doing wrong.

Comment: At no point should you adjust *both* indices on insertion of data in a circular buffer. Unless you're planning on expanding the buffer (and you're not), overlap detection should be considered an *error*. And the adjustment of `size` in initialization to `size+1` is outright wrong unless your intent is to implement what most do for circular buffers; namely sacrifice one slot for easy overlap detection (and if that is the case, you should be allocating that slot as well, and you're currently not).

Comment: I have edited my question to show a simplified version of my program.

@WhozCraig
Do you mean I shouldnt adjust both lastind and startind in addItem? I commented out the if statement that adjusts the startind if the buffer needs to overwrite but Im still getting the same error. I also allocated the empty slot like you mentioned.

Comment: Your initialize code is using `cBuff->size` before you set it.  You're using a quasi-random size, and getting correspondingly quasi-random results.  As you can now see, it is the code you didn't show originally that is causing the trouble — that's why we have to demand to see a workable example!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How could I be so dumb. Lesson learned, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the initialize code is shown, the problem is clear: you are using `cBuff->size` before you set it.

```
void initializeBuffer(CircularBuffer *cBuff, int size) {
    cBuff->cBuffItems = calloc(cBuff->size, sizeof(BufferItem));
    cBuff->size  = size + 1;
    cBuff->startInd = 0;
    cBuff->lastInd   = 0;
}
```

Consequently, you're using a quasi-random size, and getting correspondingly quasi-random results. As you can now see, it is the code you didn't show originally that is causing the trouble — that's why we have to demand to see a workable example!

You can fix it pretty trivially:

```
void initializeBuffer(CircularBuffer *cBuff, int size) {
    cBuff->cBuffItems = calloc(size + 1, sizeof(BufferItem));
    cBuff->size  = size + 1;
    cBuff->startInd = 0;
    cBuff->lastInd   = 0;
}
```

This uses the parameter `size` instead of the uninitialized element of `cBuff`. I suggest that allocating one number of items and then saying that there is a different number of them available for use is going to cause trouble.  I've opted to add one to both numbers; on the whole, though, it might be better to use the value of `size` without the increment.

You could also reorder the assignments (so you set `cBuff->size` before you allocate `cBuff->cBuffItems`); that would also work (as long as you make the allocation size consistent with the recorded size.

You should, arguably, check the result of `calloc()`.